# how do i write this out in php? (where i would use the >> to print out content)

Tags: php

i remember a while ago i used a method like this to print out content so i didnt have to use slashes every time i had to use a quotation.

```
>> 

some text here "and more text



something;
```

what was that called? and how did it look

thanks

this im gonna write down :p

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP expression <<<EOB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048481/php-expression-eob)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're talking about [heredoc syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc). Example:

```
$str = <<<EOD
Example of string
spanning multiple lines
using heredoc syntax.
EOD;
```

Comment: YES!! thank you , thank you.. it was so blurry to remember it. lol

Answer (score 0):

That's PHP [Heredocs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc). There's an example on the manual page:

```
<?php
class foo {
    public $bar = <<<EOT
bar
EOT;
}
?>
```

The heredoc starts with `<<<` folowed by an identifier, and ends with that same identifier followed by a semicolon. Note that the end identifier must start at the beginning of a line, and cannot be indented.